# HTML/CSS Dropdown input onclick not firing

Tags: html, css, input, hyperlink, onclick

I am trying to implement an search box with dropdown suggestions using CSS/HTML only. It displays fine but I cannot get the onclick event to fire when clicking on a dropdown element and the links don't work either. If I don't hide the list then it works fine, but when hidden and then displayed using the ":focus" selector of the input box it does not react to clicks anymore.

Any idea how to fix this? Is this a normal behavior for hidden elements?

It is based on [this example](http://cssdeck.com/labs/search-box-with-suggestions-dropdown), and it does not seem to work there either.

A simple example reproducing the problem:

HTML:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css" />
  </head>
    <input class="inputfield" type="text" placeholder="SEARCH...">
    <ul class="search-results">
      <li class="typeahead" onclick="console.log('test')">
        <a class="center" href="/test" >test</a>
      </li>
      <li class="typeahead" onclick="console.log('test')">
        <a class="center" href="/test" >test</a>
      </li>
      <li class="typeahead" onclick="console.log('test')">
        <a class="center" href="/test" >test</a>
      </li>
      <li class="typeahead" onclick="console.log('test')">
        <a class="center" href="/test" >test</a>
     </li>
   </ul>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
input{
  width: 300px;
  height: 26px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  outline: none;
}

ul{
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}

input:focus + ul{
  visibility: visible;
}


li{
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  border-top-style: none;
  width: 300px;
  height: 25px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  background: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

li:hover{
  background-color: lightgrey;
}

li:hover a{
  color: white;
}

a{
  color: black;
  font-size: 12px;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: My guess is that focus is lost before click event so the list is hidden and you're in fact clicking just a background, not the li element.

Comment: Thank you for your help! This seems indeed to be the issue, @CeritT  answer solves part of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the order of the triggers, as in CeritT's answer.

My suggestion is to use `transition` to make `ul` to not disappear immediately, thus allow clicking on it.

```
ul.search-results {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    transition: visibility 0.2s;
}
```

Comment: That does not seem to work for me, does it work for you?

Comment: Yes, could you check this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b_m_h/bfnoLznv/)? works for me.

Comment: My bad I had forgotten the 's'.

Comment: Accepted as answer because there is no semantic change involved (can keep onmouseclick) and also works easily for links. But @CeritT answer is also interesting. Thank you both! And sorry I cannot upvote your answers yet.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the order of triggers, focus, blur and click;

'search-results' is visible when input gets focused, so it is hidden when input is not focused. When you click on a 'li', input loses its focus and 'li' dissappears before the click event is triggered.

One solution is to change onclick to onmousedown.

Comment: Thank you! I knew it was something like but I did not know how to fix it! This is enough for my use, but out of curiosity, would there be any way to have the link work?

Comment: Using javascript like onmousedown="window.location.href='http://www.example.com'" or window.open() will do the job, but if you want to write links with a tag, since it only triggers with click, you need to make a combination with divs, input and lists that wont lose its focus when you click on a tag