# onclick action slower than css :focus selector switch

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vue-router, vue-material

I'm working with vue.js, vue-router and vue-material in my application. I have a search bar in which you can perform a global search for artists, releases and records. this looks somewhat like this:

---

### [image: search bar with example search]

The result div is currently only displayed if the input form has focus.
I do this like this in css:

```
.search-field + span {
  display: none;
}

.search-field:focus + span, .search-field:active + span {
  display: block;
}
```

This shows/hides the result span in an absolute position before all other components.

**The problem** I have now is that when I click on one of the result entries it just does nothing.

The result items displayed are of type `md-list-item` and define a `:to` property for the vue-router to perform the site navigation on-click.

I assume it does nothing because the 'click' (action) is never actually performed on the list-item itself, but on the component behind it (body). I think this happens because the `:focus` selector changes the view state (hides the result span) before the onclick event is triggered on the item.

Is there a way to delay the switch from `:focus` to normal? I tried to put the css property `transition-delay` on the `.search-field` class but that didn't bring me far.

**Edit 1**

Ifound [a similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25198996/html-css-dropdown-input-onclick-not-firing) but haven't been able to port the solution to my markup; it looks like this:

```
  <md-field class="md-toolbar-section-end searchbar md-inline grow">
    <label class="search-label">Search...</label>
    <md-input class="search-field" v-model="query"></md-input>
    <span class="result-span">
    <md-content class="results md-elevation-15 md-scrollbar md-layout" :style="{ display: displayResults ? 'flex' : 'none' }">
      <template v-for="loader in [loaderArtists, loaderReleases, loaderRecords]">
        <div :key="Math.random()">
          <md-list>
            <template v-if="loader.isLoading">
              <span>
                <md-progress-spinner :md-diameter="20" :md-stroke="3" md-mode="indeterminate"></md-progress-spinner>
              </span>
            </template>
            <template v-else>
              <template v-for="item in loader.dataSource.data">
                <md-list-item :to="item.value">
                  <md-icon>{{item.icon}}</md-icon>
                  <span class="md-list-item-text">{{item.label}}</span>
                </md-list-item>
              </template>
            </template>
          </md-list>
          <md-divider class="divider"></md-divider>
        </div>
      </template>
    </md-content>
    </span>
    <md-icon class="search-icon">search</md-icon>
  </md-field>
```

I changed the css accordingly to use the property `visibility` instead of `display` and added `transition: visibility 0.2s` to the `.result-span` class - which did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the issue by applying the solution provided in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25199467/6459948).

The reason why this didn't work in the first place was, because .2s still are too fast, I had to change it to 0.3s

**To conclude:**

I changed css to this:

```
.result-span {
  transition: visibility .3s;
}

.search-field ~ .result-span {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.search-field:focus ~ .result-span, .search-field:active ~ .result-span {
  visibility: visible;
}
```